# ImportError: No module named spwd

Tags: python, python-2.7, osx-elcapitan

Could someone help, please? I can't understand why I see this.

I'm trying to use `spwd` module from Python. I just imported it, but see this, absolutely unexpected, error when running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./library/system_users.py", line 25, in <module>
import spwd
ImportError: No module named pwd
```

I thought it should be available by default.

Python 2.7.10
pip 8.1.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
OS X El Capitan 10.11.4

I know sometimes `pip install --upgrade pip` can help. Unfortunately, not now.

Thank you for the advance.

Comment: @dooms - sorry, what do you mean? I'm not using RPM Linux. Try to use this Python module with my script, but can't import it. Developing just on my MacBook.

Comment: Did you pip Install the module pwd?

Comment: @HarshDattani of course no. I thought it should be available by default, like ``grp`` or ``pwd`` modules, for example.

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed in your comment on this question, `spwd` is a [built-in module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/), so it is usually built as you compile Python. For this reason, I would guess that `spwd` simply isn't supported on the system you are using—i.e. OS X 10.11—unless whoever built your installed version of Python made a configuration mistake or manually disabled the module.

---

However, we can do more than guess about this. When building Python, much of the system-specific configuration is handled in a script called `setup.py`. Support for many built-in modules is determined in the `detect_modules` method of the `PyBuildExt` class; the function contains the following code (taken from [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c2f86d86e6c8f5fd1ef602128b537a48f3f5c063/setup.py#L718-L723)).

```py
if (config_h_vars.get('HAVE_GETSPNAM', False) or
                config_h_vars.get('HAVE_GETSPENT', False)):
            exts.append( Extension('spwd', ['spwdmodule.c']) )
        else:
            missing.append('spwd')
```

We can see that the function adds the Extension `'spwd'` (which consists of the `spwdmodule.c` source file) to the lists of extensions only when `config_h_var` has either `HAVE_GETSPNAM` or `HAVE_GETSPENT`. The strings in `config_h_vars`  correspond to the macros that are defined in the `pyconfig.h` header file that is generated when you run Python's `configure` script before compiling.

According to comments generated with the `pyconfig.h` file, `HAVE_GETSPNAM` is defined (to 1) if your system has the `getspname` function, and `HAVE_GETSPENT` is defined (again, to 1) if your system has the `getspent` function.

The problem is that OS X 10.11 (and, seemingly, newer versions of macOS) have neither of these functions. (The manual for gnulib confirms this, albeit for an older version of Mac OS X. See [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/getspnam.html) and [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/getspent.html).) Thus, when compiling Python on OS X/macOS, the `spwd` is not built, and so you see an `ImportError` when you try to import it on that system.

---

[dooms's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36527581) suggests installing `spwd` from Anaconda. Of course, this isn't expected to work since `spwd` is a built-in module, not a package you would expect to install from a package manager. I also don't see a `spwd` package on PyPI or any Anaconda channels.

However, since Python does not seem to prevent you from installing a module named `spwd` (at least when you don't have the built-in `spwd`), it is conceivable that you could install some sort of drop-in replacement `spwd` made for macOS. macOS and iOS use `/etc/master.passwd` instead of `/etc/shadow`, but maybe it might still be possible to make something work.

Unfortunately, as of this writing, it doesn't seem like any such replacement exists for macOS. I would treat any software that requires `spwd` as incompatible with macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

> Anaconda is a completely free Python distribution (including for commercial use and redistribution). It includes more than 400 of the most popular Python packages for science, math, engineering, and data analysis. See the packages included with Anaconda and the Anaconda changelog.

After that, just type :

```
conda install spwd
```

Comment: Is it okay in case of proper usage of Python modules on OS X now (yet another modules manager for Python)? Could someone else prove it / agree with it?

Comment: Also, I executed my script on a remote Debian server. It works fine there, because there's a module present.

Comment: Don't worry Anaconda is a well known distribution.